# I would like to format my app log in unix

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a log file like this:

```
[loggerid:1234-4567] api:api1() 5.91
[loggerid:7899-45671234] api:api12345() 11.00
[loggerid:3333-45671234564] api:api12345789() 11.05
```

And I need output like this:

- First column should be string between `:` and `-`
- Second column should be string between `:` and `(`
- I need only rows where column 3 > 10.
- All columns should be fixed width

```
7899 api12345    11.0 
3333 api12345789 11.05
```

Comment: Don't just throw requirements out. Show some effort solving the problem, and ask questions when you are stuck. Having said that, `awk` would have no problem handling the third and fourth points, and could probably do the formatting (points 1 and 2) using the `sub` function without much pain .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your lines all follow that exact pattern, you can use a combination of `awk` and `column` (the second will help you get fixed width fields):

```
$ awk -F'[-: (]' '$NF>10{print $2,$5,$NF}' log | column -t
7899  api12345     11.00
3333  api12345789  11.05
```

#### Explanation

*`awk -F'[-: (]'`: set awk's field separator to any of `-`,`:`,`(` or space. This allows us to find the substrings you want as fields.

- `$NF>10`: if the last field (`NF` is the number of fields so `$NF` is the value of the last field) is greater than 10.
- `print $2,$5,$NF` : print the 2nd field (the value between the first `:` and the first `-` in this case), the 5th field (the value between the second `:` and first `(` here) and the last field.

Finally, we pass the output of this `awk` through `column -t` to make it into a fixed width table.

Please note that this will not work if any of your lines have different combinations of the `-`,`:`,`(` or space.